# How to render text in a CALayer using NSLayoutManager?

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nslayoutmanager, nstextstorage

I am using the trio of `NSLayoutManager, NSTextStorage & NSTextContainer` to render text in a layer-backed `NSView`.

I am under the impression that the view will be more performant if I can override `wantsUpdateLayer` to return true and thus be using layers more fully. **Is this true?**

However, all examples I have seen of using `NSLayoutManager` say that you need to place the following call within `drawRect`:

```
layoutManager.drawGlyphsForGlyphRange(glyphRange, atPoint: NSMakePoint(0, 0))
```

**How would you perform the equivalent call within `updateLayer` or some other more layer-oriented place instead?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom `CALayer` and overrode the `drawInContext` method as below:

```
override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext!) {
    NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()

    var nsgc = NSGraphicsContext(CGContext: ctx, flipped: false)
    NSGraphicsContext.setCurrentContext(nsgc)

    NSColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0, 0, 84, 24))

    lm.drawGlyphsForGlyphRange(glyphRange, atPoint: NSMakePoint(0, 0))  // location of textContainer

    NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()

}
```

This gets the job done, but

1. I'm not sure if there are any performance implications to saving and restoring the graphics context as above.
2. I am unsure how the same would be achieved in the NSView's `updateLayer` method as that does not have a context to use.

Comment: in UIKit, a view is just a wrapper around a CALayer that handles the user interaction. On OS X I am using a custom view in a similar way to draw text. So drawing in CALayer is not an issue.

Comment: Saving and restoring graphicscontext once or twice every drawInContext call should not be an issue. Don't call it hundreds of times within the same function though. And you can always profile your code if it appears slow.